# Remove spaces and commas at the end and beginning of comma separated string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Given that I can get strings like this:

```
dog, cat, person

,people, boys, girls, 

people, boys, police ,
```

How would I delete the possible spaces and commas at the end and beginning of strings. So for example, the last two strings would be converted to:

```
people,boys,girls
people,boys,police
```

Moreover, I would like to delete the spaces between the commas.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a character class with commas and spaces, and the end-of-string anchor `$`:

```
str = str.replace(/^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$/g, '');
str = str.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ',');
```

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my question...I would need to delete the beginning commas too, and also the spaces before and after commas...

Comment: I just realized that the second regex, deletes de comma too. I just want to delete the trailing spaces between commas..

Comment: @HommerSmith, no it doesn't. However I realized, that I was missing the global modifier to catch multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

```
'people, boys, police, '.replace(/[, ]+$/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might do it for you:

```
(^[,. ]+|[,. ]+$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
str.replace(/^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$/g, '').replace(/,[,\s]*,/g, ',');
```

here str is the string you need to parse.